# Прогресс для отдельного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

Прогресс для отдельного элемента `.container`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка в скрипте? При прокрутке блока `.container` влево-вправо прогресс `#progress` должен менять свою ширину в зависимости от того, насколько прокручен блок.

```js
var indicator = document.querySelector('#progress');
var progressIndicator = function() {
    indicator.style.width = (window.scrollX / (document.querySelector('.container').offsetWidth - window.innerWidth) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", progressIndicator);
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {overflow: hidden;}

#progress {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Comment: вы вроде не первый день на ресурсе. мы сами должны догадаться что здесь вообще не так, и что вы ожидаете от этого кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если что-то не работает, надо сначала проверять, запускается ли вообще функция) Простой console.log() в progressIndicator: Не работает. Событие добавили на window, а скролл происходит в container. Его и стоит отслеживать.

Вдобавок:

1. container.scrollLeft — сколько пикселей прошло,
2. container.scrollWidth — реальная внутренняя ширина, с учетом скролла,
3. container.clientWidth — внутренняя ширина без учета скролла.

```js
var indicator = document.querySelector('#progress');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

var progressIndicator = function(e) {
  var scrolled = container.scrollLeft;
  var full_scroll = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;
  
  indicator.style.width = (100 * scrolled / full_scroll).toFixed(1) + "%";
};

container.addEventListener("scroll", progressIndicator);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progress {
  background-color: #f70;
  position: fixed;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну кстати, такой прогресс имеет смысл только если скрыть скроллбар. Иначе они соответствуют друг другу 1:1 )